# IOS sdk navigation event upon return

Tags: ios, events, sdk, navigation

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to get the event when navigation is returning from a controller.

for example calling this from a view controller
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

then I want to catch the event in the calling view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewWillAppear gets called when navigation is returning. What I've done was to set some indicators in the calling view controller from the current view controller when data has changed. Then in the calling view controller when viewWillAppear gets called, I'm just checking the indicators to know if something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIViewController method

> isMovingFromParentViewController

It is defined as "Returns a Boolean value that indicates that the view controller is in the process of being removed from its parent."

There is also a isMovingToParentViewController for the reverse. Same with isBeingPresented and isBeingDismissed for other interaction with view controllers.

More info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController